# JQuery - fade in (animate) img with replace and attr change

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-animate

**HTML:**

```
            <td>
                <div class="content" style=""><img src="FoodBlockPic.png" style="max-width: 100%;"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content" style=""><img src="DeliveryBlockPic2.png" style="max-width: 100%;" id="deliveryPIC"></div>
            </td>
            <td>
                <div class="content" style=""><img src="PickupBlockPic2.png" style="max-width: 100%;"></div>
            </td>

        </tr>
```

**JQuery:**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#deliveryPIC').hover(function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace("DeliveryBlockPic2.png", "DeliveryBlockPicAlt.png");
        $(this).attr("src", src);
        // $('#deliveryPIC').fadeIn("slow");
        // $('#deliveryPIC').hide();
        $('#deliveryPIC').fadeIn();
      }, function() {
        var src = $(this).attr("src").replace( "DeliveryBlockPicAlt.png", "DeliveryBlockPic2.png");
        $(this).attr("src", src).stop();
        // $('#deliveryPIC').fadeIn("slow");
        // $('#deliveryPIC').hide();
        $('#deliveryPIC').fadeIn();
      });
    });
  </script>
```

I would simply like to animate the transition between the original picture and it's replaced src picture on hover and animate again when off hover. I am having trouble figuring out how to do this b/c just fade in does not work, fade in with hide makes the transition kind of glitchy, and the top fade in statement also does nothing by itself... Would mouseon, mouseoff be best here, and if so, how would I animate that transition? With my current code, the image swap works properly, but I can't seem to figure out the animation/fade-in/fade-out. Thanks for the help!!! :D

Comment: did you try `fadeIn(5000)` like that?

Comment: Yes, on your suggestion I just did - but that is not working either.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to replace the `src` attribute you need to know that you have to wait until the image will finish the `fadeOut` animation before you can replace the `src` ,otherwise, the image just disappear but not with animation.

```js
$('img').hover(function(){
  var img = $(this);
  img.fadeOut(function(){
    img.attr('src', img.attr('data-src2')).fadeIn();
  });
}, function(){
    var img = $(this);
    img.fadeOut(function(){
      img.attr('src', img.attr('data-src1')).fadeIn();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JQvA.png" data-src1="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JQvA.png" data-src2="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4qVb.png" />
```

If you want that the `fadeIn` and the `fadeOut` will occurred simultaneously, you have to put the both of the images and hide the second. When mouse over you can animate them both simultaneously. Something like this:

```js
$('.wrapper').hover(function(){
  $('img').fadeToggle('slow');  
}, function(){
  $('img').fadeToggle('slow');  
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position:relative;  
  width:69px;
  height:68px;
}

.wrapper img {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}

.wrapper img:last-child {
  display:none;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/1JQvA.png" />
  <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4qVb.png" />
</div>
```